# Cannot find module gulp.js

Tags: reactjs, sharepoint, gulp, sharepoint-online, spfx

I checked-out a solution from TFS and I have this error in my console when trying to clean & build a solution - > **Error: Cannot find module 'C:..\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js'**.

Any idea why is not found?

I tried already to reinstall npm and gulp ( also globally ).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. `cd /usr/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/v8flags`
2. `sudo node fetch.js`

And that's it. The last instruction will create the required file.